# upgarde to 2.2 android OS- X8 mobile

Tags: 2.2-froyo, 2.1-eclair, sony-ericsson-xperia-x8

can anyone provide me the simple steps to upgrade to 2.2 from 2.1 android OS for X8 Xperia mobile. If so, is that fine to do myself without the help of sony erricson departmental store ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I update the OS in my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-the-os-in-my-device)

Answer (score 2):

There's no official upgrade to 2.2 for X8 Xperia, [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Ericsson_Xperia_X8). You can install a third-party ROM, though -- it seems the latest [Cyanogenmod 7.1 is available](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices/sony-ericsson-xperia-x8) for this device. Which is even better, considering that ROM is based on Gingerbread 2.3 instead of Froyo.