# How can I upgrade to the latest Android version?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, android-versions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update the OS in my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-the-os-in-my-device)

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace and would like to upgrade to Android 4. How can I do that?

Comment: The duplicate should cover the generic "how", and also provides links to several community wiki questions which cover the major Android updates and their availability. However, if you have a specific issue when attempting to update your device, feel free to pose that as a question.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is eligible for an operating system upgrade, you'll see a System Update message pop up in your notification bar (along the top of the screen).  You will only see this, though, when Google, your phone manufacturer and/or your cellphone provider have customized the operating system for your device.

Comment: Thank you. I m using 2.2.1. Galaxy ace samsung. how can check for that manually

Comment: If there is some evidence an update may be ready for your phone and you feel you just need to have your phone check again, one way that was rumoured to work is to open up your dialer and dial `*#*#checkin#*#*`.  It is unclear whether this actually works, but it's worth a shot.  As for which version you may be entitled to, I had a look at the Wikipedia page for your phone and the latest update released was 2.3.6.  Did you hear or read somewhere that Android 4 would be made available for your phone?

Comment: Ok I am not aware of this.can I upgrade it to 2.3? How

Comment: If, even after using the `checkin` trick, you're still not prompted to upgrade, consider contacting your cellphone provider or manufacturer to figure out whether your entitled to the upgrade (in your country, or with your provider).  If there's anything you feel suggests you should be seeing the upgrade (a friend with the same phone has an upgrade, or you saw something on the internet somewhere) consider editing your question to include such details.

Comment: Ok. I wull check with them. I did not get any such notification