# How to update my galaxy s?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update the OS in my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-the-os-in-my-device)

I have a samsung galaxy s GT-I9000 and I want to update it. I have android 2.3.3 but I read there's an update to 2.3.5 or even 2.3.6 with a value pack. I plugged my phone on my pc and I installed Kies but it tells me I have the latest version. Is android 2.3.3 the latest version for my device? What can I do ?

Thanks!

ps: in that case I want to remain using only official updates.
ps2: the OTA updater tells me theres' no update available...

Comment: this is obviously not a duplicate of that one. I know HOW to update the phone but my question here is why is Kies not giving me the latest update and HOW can I do to get it anyway ?

Comment: actually, i disagree. That is a community wiki of How to update your device. which would cover your question. You will also notice that it says "Just because a new version has been announced doesn't mean it's immediately available for your device.". That question is so there are not multiple question of "how do i update my device".

Comment: Ok you make a point. I didn't see it in that way. Flagging as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If Kies isn't giving you an update then more than likely your operator hasn't released the update. You could still install the value pack but it will more than likely void your warranty. Details on how to install it are [here](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/galaxy-s-gets-official-value-pack-firmware-xxjw4-includes-touchwiz-4/).

Comment: @jafar, if nulling your warranty is of no concern you can always search the web for custom 3rd party roms for your device. I think Samsung didn't bother giving the Galaxy s1 an ICS release because ICS was designed to support multi core devices which the S1 is not.

Comment: Yeah, usually a 3rd party custom rom is the best way to go. Some of them are great.

Comment: Yes I know XDA etc. I used to flash my own phone every day. Here I want to do it in the 'newbie' way because I want to reproduce a standard and official environment (my company won't give any support to hacked devices).