# How do I upgrade my Galaxy i5510 2.2 froyo to 2.3 Gingerbread?

Tags: updates, operating-system, samsung-galaxy-551

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update the OS on my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-the-os-on-my-device)

can any one tell me how to upgrade Samsung galaxy i5510 2.2 froyo to 2.3 Gingerbread

Answer (score 2):

I have done this on my Samsung Galaxy I5510, just follow these steps:

**Required**: phone's USB driver should be installed

1. Run Odin_Downloader_v4.42 software
2. Select "CALLISTO_ops" file in "OPS"
3. Check "one package" in the options menu
4. Select "I5510XWKPH_I5510XEZKP2_XEZ" file in "One Package" (last button)
5. Switch off phone, then press <kbd>T</kbd> + the power button to go to Download mode
6. In the Odin_Downloader software window, check that "COM Port Mapping" is YELLOW
   (if it's not yellow then it means USB not recognizing your device)
7. After making sure it's connected, click the "Start" button and wait until it finishes
   (all of these process can be checked in "message box" left side)
8. It's done!

For more information, go to this [link](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/android-forum/210957-universal-gingerbread-root-unroot-2-3-3-2-3-7-a.html).

Answer (score 0):

- [How to Update Galaxy 551 I5510 to XWKP5 Gingerbread 2.3.4 European Firmware](http://androidadvices.com/update-galaxy-551-i5510-xwkp5-gingerbread-234-european-firmware/)
- [Update Samsung Galaxy 551 I5510 to XWKP5 Gingerbread 2.3.4 ...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpxK_8osd5g) Video-Guide on Youtube
- [I5510XWKPA Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread Stock ROM Download](http://www.samsdroid.com/2011/11/i5510xwkpa-android-236-gingerbread.html)
- [How to upgrade samsung galaxy i5510 from android 2.2 to 2.3.4? - Pls give me the link for downloading these files and the steps or procedure for how to do it :: Ask Me Fast](http://www.askmefast.com/categorydetail.php?cmd=search&qtype=answered&q=How%20to%20upgrade%20samsung%20galaxy%20i5510%20from%20android%202.2%20to%202.3.4?) hm, was that all you?

Well, and a bunch more, e.g. for India and other things. Due to missing details in your question, this could become a rather long list -- which is not much loved here, so I'd better stop at this place. Hopefully, one of the above links works out for you -- otherwise, please re-formulate your question as suggested :)

Comment: Not cool, dude.