# Can I install takju ROM on unit with yakjuxw?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, rom-flashing, 4.2-jelly-bean

I bought my Galaxy Nexus a couple of months before Jelly Bean 4.2 was announced. It got updated to 4.0.4 fine, but did not find any 4.1 update at all. So I found [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/26027/3075) which informed me of units that had ROMs updated by Samsung instead of Google for whatever reason. And my unit is of the Samsung update legacy, `yakjuxw`.

Since by the time I had concrete info on this `yakju`, `takju` or whatever the 4.2 release was nearing, I decided against flashing to `yakju` 4.1.2, and resorted to camp Android's [factory image download page](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images). And then 4.2 OTA rolled out on the 13th. Only for the `takju` units that is. The download page was similarly updated. But I am running out of patience, hence the question.

tl;dr refer to the title. I would like to know if there's any issues with flashing `takju` or a `yakju` device.

Comment: There are no issues changing between the two. As far as which is better? They are essentially the same with the one difference being that takju phones receive updates quicker. http://webtrickz.com/easiest-way-to-change-galaxy-nexus-from-yakjuxw-non-yakju-to-android-4-0-4-yakjutakju/ This describes what to do. Its a large article, so I'm only giving the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can install a takju ROM on a yakjuxw device.  For that matter, you can also install a yakju ROM, or one of many other custom Galaxy Nexus ROMs (e.g. Cyanogenmod) on a device that originally had yakjuxw.

I have personally flashed both yakju and takju ROMs on my Galaxy Nexus, which originally had a yakjux (Canada) ROM.  The only possible issue is that flashing a new ROM may erase user data from the SD card (pictures, SMS messages, wifi information, etc.).  So you may want to back up your data before flashing.

Comment: Thanks, choosing this answer on the account of personal experience.

Comment: go for takju, seems this is the first updated. i have yakju and waited about 3-4 weeks to receive 4.2 OTA update ,after the first takju OTA became available

Answer (score 2):

This is an exert from A Guide to Manually Install Android 4.2 Takju on Non-Yakju Galaxy Nexus written 14th Nov. 2012 available at: http://webtrickz.com/guide-to-manually-install-android-4-2-takju-on-non-yakju-galaxy-nexus/

Following the availability of Nexus 4 and Nexus 10, Google has begun the rollout of Android 4.2 Jelly Bean OTA update for Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 7 as well. Android 4.2 is currently available only for Takju variant of GSM/HSPA+ Galaxy Nexus and luckily Google has also released the Android 4.2 factory image for Takju Galaxy Nexus.
Apparently, Non-Yakju Galaxy Nexus users wont receive this new update anytime soon as their phone is updated by Samsung whereas Yakju & Takju firmware are updated directly by Google.
However, users with adequate technical know-how **can easily convert** their non-yakju (**yakjuxw**, yakjuux, yakjusc, yakjuzs, yakjudv, yakjukr and yakjujp) device to Takju to receive prompt future OTA updates from Google.

The above link will take you through the various steps needed to achieve what you desire (**inc. video tutorial for Step 3**). So yes you can install takju ROM on unit with yakjuxw.