# Galaxy Nexus stuck on 4.1.1 and super slow

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, ota-update

I own a Galaxy Nexus running `Android 4.1.1`. The build number is `JRO03C.I9250XWLH2`. Since the update to 4.1.1 the phone behaves very very slow. Also, a friend of mine has the same phone (we bought it together) already has received the update to `4.2.x` months ago.

I'm wondering if anyone else has this problem of being stuck with 4.1.1 and understands what the reason is.

What's the current standard procedure to upgrade the phone manually instead of waiting for the OTA?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Jelly Bean on the Galaxy Nexus - forcing an update?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26027/)