# Galaxy Nexus call freezing

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.1-jelly-bean, calls

I've bought **two** Galaxy Nexus phones about a month and a half ago. I'm experiencing phone freezing on calls on both hence I doubt it has anything to do with the phone but rather with software.

### When does the phone freeze

1. **Someone calls me.**

   1. I drag to green to initiate the phone call
   2. Display changes to *in-call mode* which displays the big red *stop the call* button
   3. Phone freezes
2. **I try calling someone.**

   1. I open contacts
   2. Select a contact and phone number
   3. The moment I select Phone calling app (because I also have Skype and it asks me which one to use)
   4. Phone freezes

I tried un-installing Skype but there was no difference.

### Other possible candidates

I haven't tested thoroughly but I suspect if I have a phone number in my contacts saved with spaces (or whatever that blank button on contact number keyboard is - could be some dialling pause maybe?) my phone freezes. When I removed spaces I usually was able to make a call. But I haven't tested this thoroughly and am not 100% sure of it.

I should point out that freezing doesn't happen on every call. It's sporadic but often enough to be extremely annoying. Makes me look ridiculous in the eyes of others what kind a phone I'm using.

As I [read on the web](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37485) others [are having](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35583) same [freezing issues](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13674) on their Nexus phones. Some indicate it may be a problem with battery status info reporting back to phone hence battery removal solves the issue for a day... But this problem has apparently been present for almost 2 years and it seems to be related to OS without any relation to installed apps.

It's interesting/sad/worrying that something primarily supposed to be a phone became incapable of being one. :)

#### Info

- unlocked Galaxy Nexus bought on Amazon.de
- non-rooted Jelly Bean 4.1.2
- UI language is English (UK)

Comment: Is it possible for you to upgrade to 4.2.2? You would need to unlock the bootloader and install a different version of the stock ROM on the devices. This might fix the problem. There's a post about upgrading [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25977).

Comment: @onik: It's Galaxy Nexus. It's running 4.2.2 since it came out. But I'm not interested in rooting and other ROMs as they never work as expected. It turns out that it's a HW issue anyway. If you root you have the possibility of having an app that disabled proximity altogether and it prevents freezing, but rooting is required. As this is more of a 20% freeze rate on phone usage (or maybe even a bit less) I'm not going to root. And I intend to take both devices to service before warranty expires.

Comment: Rooting is not a necessity to change the device's ROM, I used my GNex for a year with a newer ROM with the trick. The Rom isn't a custom ROM, it's the stock version but with updates coming straight from Google as opposed to Samsung, which has a substantial delay. Also, your question said it runs 4.1.2, that's why I suggested this.

Comment: @onik: It's an old question and at the time of asking I was running 4.1.2 that was latest at that time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per users it seems that the only *official* thing to do is to change mainboard that's somewhat faulty on this C8 series. Service centre should handle such situation.