# Yakjuxw to Yakju/Takju, will it corrupt or destroy my Galaxy Nexus yakjuxw?

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.2-jelly-bean

My galaxy nexus is of yakjuxw variant. Will it not destroy my phone if I change it to takju or yakju version? I'm just aware that doing so will delete user files/settings.

Answer (score 2):

I did not have any issue making a similar change myself, using the [guides online](http://www.androidauthority.com/galaxy-nexus-gt-i9250-android-4-1-1-jelly-bean-unofficial-rom-102120/) that walk you through switching your Samsung or Telco branded Galaxy Nexus (on the Samsung upgrade track) to a Google branded one on the much faster Google upgrade track.

Don't skip any steps, and be sure to back everything up, and be aware that you are probably voiding your warranty. I linked to a 4.1.1 upgrade guide; I am sure there are newer ones out, though most of the guide will be identical.

Comment: I noticed that the guide is for upgrading to an unofficial version, a guide for the official update can be found in my answer to [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25977/). I used this guide and upgrades up to 4.2 worked over the air with no problems.

Comment: thanks. my phone is locked to a network and im on postpaid plan. Is the guide still applicable to upgrade my Yakjuxw to Yakju or Takju? Or is it should be Yakjuxw AND an Unlocked Galaxy nexus?

Comment: Other than possibly voiding your warranty, I am not aware of any reason you could not upgrade your phone @peterdums. I could, of course, be wrong. Notably if the carrier has some required pre-installed app to use the service.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that you will have no problems if you follow the steps. I upgraded yakju .

Also this did not void my warranty. I had the motherboard replaced sometime after upgrade.

Comment: thanks! Is the replacement of your motherboard has nothing to do that your phone was upgraded to yakju?

Comment: i don't think so, because i'm using yakju ever since. with no issues.
Now i'm running 4.2. with OTA from google