# How to upgrade Android on the Samsung Galaxy Ace

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, operating-system

I have an Samsung Galaxy Ace that came preinstalled with Android v2.3.4 (Gingerbread I believe)

I've searched the internet everywhere and couldn't find a way to do so that gave clear instructions on what to do.

But I would also like to ask, if I was to update to say 4.1 (the latest I believe) would the phone then start to lag as it is not such a powerful phone. (800MHz CPU + 300MB RAM)

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Have you seen [How do I update the OS on my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510)

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can upgrade your OS, although the process isn't without risk.

There's an [entire board devoted to the Galaxy Ace](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1164) at xda  - [here's a good post which should get you started](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1225493).  From the quick skim I've done over a few posts there seems to be a massive warning of not to use [ROM Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager) (a popular tool in the ROM community) as it'll [brick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_%28electronics%29) your device.

Once your device is rooted you can then install a ROM - [here's a link to a Cyanogenmod 10 based ROM for the ace](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1874920) running Android 4,1, I think.  Be careful to read the instructions and take note of the stuff that doesn't work. If you get stuck - [there's lots of help out there](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=android%20noobs%20guide%20to%20rooting%20installing%20roms&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=73a2df482f71c0a7&bpcl=35466521&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=2560&bih=1475)

Good luck.

Comment: Haha. Wow. It's that tricky? Android is heaps different to iOS! Anyways, I'll give it a try and let you know what happens. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah - Samsung phones are a little more difficult that other devices.  Make sure you follow the instructions to the letter and you should be fine.  Don't forget to mark this post as the answer so other users with a similar question can benefit from the help too