# Update Android 2.3.4 on HTC Sensation

Tags: htc-sense

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update the OS on my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-the-os-on-my-device)

I have a an HTC Sensation with Android 2.3.4. I tried to check for updates. It says that there are no new updates. Is there any way to update my system to Android 4.0 manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://blog.htc.com/2012/03/ics/) from HTC's website should help you. This might depend on your location and carrier. So please go through the site.

Another option, if you are ready to *void your warranty*, you can go for a custom ROM like [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/).