# how to upgrade my android phone?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update the OS on my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-the-os-on-my-device)

I've got Sony Ericsson X8 currently running android v1.6. Now I want to upgrade it to gingerbread.

Provide me some solutions...?

Thank You...

Comment: Duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/7574?

Answer (score 0):

XDA Developers forums is the go-to place for all things android.
[Sony Ericsson X8 XDA Developers Thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=921652)