# ZTE StarTrail : Android Update 2.2 to 2.3.3 or an other version

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, 2.2-froyo, updates, zte-blade

I'm new android user. I just buy un android phone: [ZTE StarTrail](http://media01.viva-images.com/classifieds/79/2/48633034/large/1.jpg?dt=f333e4c6af8f3a6a86843d3d48647dde). The current version is android 2.2 (Froyo). I would like update my system to 2.3.3 or an other version. i saw there is version each for device (HTC, Samsung ....). I don't found a version for my device. Where can I found android a version that is specifically designed for ZTE StarTrail ?

Thanks

Comment: I couldn't find "StarTrail" on ZTE's official site.  Does this phone also go by a different name?  Do you maybe have a model number?

Comment: Ok thanks. I visited  ZTE's official site before post my question here. My carrier no longer sells this device. Therefore, here isn't support for this device.

Comment: Have you seen: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-the-os-on-my-device If there's not an official update for your device, and if no one has made a custom ROM for it, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should check with the manufacturer of your device if they have an official upgrade available.  If so, they will either provide the download (with installation instructions) themselves, or forward you to your carrier's support.

If there is no official upgrade, your only option is to find out if there are any 3rd-party ROMs available from Android community developers.  Best places to look for such ROMs are [xda-developers forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) or [RootzWiki](http://rootzwiki.com/index), for example.  Keep in mind that installing custom ROMs usually involves modifications to your phone that will void your warranty with the carrier and/or manufacturer.