# Jellybean on Motorola Defy

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, motorola-defy

What is the procedure to install Android 4.1 or 4.2 on a Motorola Defy (MB525)? My phone is currently rooted and running Cyanogenmod 9.

Comment: A candidate for [How do I update the OS on my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/16575) :) As you're running CM9: check whether CM10 is available for your device, which comes with JB 4.1 (CM10) or 4.2 (CM10.1).

Answer (score 0):

Go to quarx2k.ru, and select one of the 2nd-boot folders. These work for both MB525 and MB526. Simply download and flash, making sure to wipe the system, data, and cache first. If you want google apps, go to goo.im and select 4.2 or 4.1, depending on what version works.

If you want a really stable version, select 4.0 or 4.1. 
4.2 was not developed on very much, but 4.3 works, I use it daily.
It's not completely stable, but certainly usable.
4.4 works, but I really don't recommend it as of yet.

Hope this helps, message me if you want more information.

Comment: For people who may consider flagging this answer, the site listed does appear to be legit. See https://github.com/Quarx2k

Comment: Yeah, Quarx2k is the main developer of unofficial CM versions for Motorola Defy and Defy+. Check out his posts on xda.com, they help explain his ROMs and whatnot.