# How do I flash a Samsung device using the distribution on samsung-updates.com?

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung, stock-rom

I'm hoping to flash the stock rom back onto my device so I can [update the PRL](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/54214/7425). I downloaded the file on [samsung-updates.com](http://www.samsung-updates.com). The file that I download was found ["Firmware archive" for Sprint's SPH-L720 (Galaxy S4)](http://samsung-updates.com/device/?id=SPH-L720&details=Galaxy_S_4_Sprint).

A comment said the SPR was for regular users and the XAS one was for engineers. Not exactly sure what that means, but I downlaoded the SPR file changelist 1927016

> SPR-L720VPUEMJA-20131030154609.zip

Now when I look inside I have two files,

1. `L720VPUEMJA_L720SPTEMJA_L720VPUEMJA_HOME.tar.md5`
2. `SS_DL.dll`

What does these files do? Why do I do with the .dll? How do I flash my device with it? Do I simply load the .zip into Clockworkmod and boot up? Should I, or should I not wipe cache and Dalvik after I do that? I've already backed up my current version of CM and data using CWM.

Answer (score 1):

Is `SPR-L720VPUEMJA-20131030154609.zip` stock ROM? If yes, you can use the [Odin tool](http://www.android.gs/download-odin-3-04/) to flash that ROM.

I assume have already installed Samsung Kies (so phone drivers are installed). With this done, open Odin (don't change any settings). Load `L720VPUEMJA_L720SPTEMJA_L720VPUEMJA_HOME.tar.md5` into the PDA section into the ROM. Put your phone into Download Mode (Vol Down + Home + Power), and plug it into Odin. Odin should be able to detect that phone. When it does, start the flashing process.

Comment: No, I don't have Samsung Klies installed -- I'm using Linux. And, I don't have the Odin tool either? Can I just flash this ROM using CWM? I'm on a rooted phone already.

Comment: Take a look at [Heimdall](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/heimdall/info) then, which is a pendant to [Odin](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/odin/info), but also runs on Linux/MacOS.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I'm not really sure if you can flash stock ROM using CWM recovery. Odin / Heimdall (as mentioned by Izzy) are the recommended tools for flashing stock ROM.

Comment: You should use Hemidall for this, it is far less error prone and sites like the one you mentioned tend to have the files set up to do that. If you are unrooting you need the stock recovery also so CWM is out.

Comment: You need the Samsung USB drivers, which come with Kies, however, for anyone using Odin/Hemidall you need to kill ALL kies processes on your PC as they may interfere with Odin/Hemidall and cause unexpected results.