# Is it possible to upgrade an Orange Cool Tablet? (Android 2.3 Cortex A8)

Tags: updates, rom-flashing

Someone gave to me an Orange Cool Android 2.3 Tablet (it's a Brazilian brand, Model [tb7800](http://www.orangecool.com/cool/produtos/tablet/tb7800.html)), complaining about slowness and hang ups.

*I did some research with the aim of flashing a better ROM, however this model is not well-known and I'm kind of lost among all the different ROMs and architectures, so I would appreciate if someone could just point me in the right direction...*

**First of all**: is there any better ROM compatible with this device? These are the details reported by CPU-Z:

```
Model: OR-TB7800 (rk29sdk)
Display: eng.koffu.20111209.175.607, 800x480 
Android: 2.3.1, 
Kernel architecture armv7l, version 2.6.32.27 
CPU: ARM Cortex A8, 1 core, rev. r3p2, 408Mhz-1Ghz 
GPU: Vendor= Vivante Corp, Renderer=GC800 core. 
Total RAM: 271 MB Internal, Storage: 1GB
```

**Second**: if the answer is yes, I would appreciate some hints with regards to the recommended ROM and flash procedure (just some hints, I'll do my homework and continue from there, I promise!). On the contrary, if the answer to the above is no, is there anything that you would recommend me besides rooting the device to uninstall some bloatware (Facebook, etc.). The IPS display seems good and the tablet is as new, it would be a shame if I can't find some good use for it...

Thanks in advance for the help,

Comment: Please see [How do I update the OS on my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/16575) and [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575).

Comment: @Izzy: maybe I should have written my question differently. I know where are the resources explaining how to root and find ROMs, but my problem is that, while looking those resources, I can't find information about this specific tablet. So my question is: does this mean that is is not possible to upgrade, or what should I look for instead?

Comment: True, not all devices have this option. If the manufacturer doesn't provide any updates, and the device is used just "by a few", not having a developers community – then you're probably out of luck. How to possibly adapt a ROM from some "closely related hardware" is beyond the scope of this site, as it requires development skills; maybe such a question is welcome at [SO] (please check before asking there, as I'm not 100% sure).