# How to upgrade android from 4.2.2 to 4.4 kitkat in XOLO Q1010?

Tags: updates, 4.2-jelly-bean, 4.4-kitkat

I have bought XOLO Q1010 it has Android version 4.2.2.
Is it possible to upgrade to Android version 4.4 KitKat? if yes then how?

Thanks.

Comment: Please see: [How do I update the OS on my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/16575)