# Format and fresh install

Tags: operating-system

Is there any option for android phones to format like we do in computers and fresh install with a new OS?

I have searched a lot but all are going for custom ROM, and I am not interested in custom ROM, as they are basically a few tweaks. I want to install new OS in my phone like we do in our PC. Can anyone help?

Comment: What kind of "new OS" are you hoping to install, if not a custom ROM?

Comment: Then I'd suggest you take a look into our [rom-flashing tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom-flashing/info), where you find some basic explanations plus links to more details on the topic.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want a fresh start with your phone, you don't need to reinstall the OS at all, because OS files and user apps and data are stored separately. In normal use, the OS partition is read-only. All you need to do is a *factory reset*. This wipes all user data and apps, but doesn't usually touch the SD card. The process to follow is slightly different for different phones, but there's usually two ways: either reboot into *recovery mode*, which has a "factory reset" menu item, or from Settings → Backup & Reset.

Comment: But if we reset only the data will be wiped out but the OS will be the same. suppose if I have ICS, even after factory reset it will be ICS. I want to fresh install either ICS or Jellybean or any other version.

Comment: To get a new Android version, you either have to apply an update from the manufacturer (if one is available), or install a custom ROM based on the newer version. Does [the answer to this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/12442) help?

Answer (score 1):

For Nexus devices, you can use the official Factory Images from Google:
https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images

This will even let you upgrade to a newer version using a "fresh install."

I used this when my Nexus 9 was giving an error trying to update. It worked like a new device.