# Update Android on HTC Evo 4G

Tags: updates, adb, fastboot

I have a rooted FreedomPop HTC Evo 4G PC36100 with CyanogenMod 2.6.37.6. My Android version is 2.3.7. Beseband version is 2.15.00.01.15.

How can I update Android to the latest version? Is it possible? There's no button in the Settings to update, so I assume I will have to use some manual method.

I use Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca. I installed Fastboot and Android Debug Bridge.

Maybe there's a custom rom I could install that would update the Android version? Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: The EVO is almost 5 years old. I doubt there are any ROMs for it that are even close to the current Android release. Since it never got an update past 2.3.7, there's no official code for other developers to work off of beyond that. There were some experimental 4.0 ROMs back in the day but they were all incredibly buggy. Might still be floating around on XDA, though.

Comment: Pointers: [How do I update Android on my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/16575) / [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Comment: @eldarerathis That's unfortunate. I suppose I'll get a newer phone. Do you know of a good used smartphone I could get that has a camera as good or better than the evo (8mp)?

Comment: If you're using FreedomPop, I'd recommend looking at the [devices they support](https://forums.freedompop.com/discussion/145/supported-phones-what-phones-can-i-activate-with-freedompop-on-byod) and using that to figure out which one fits your needs best.

Comment: @eldarerathis No, FreedomPop sucks. I stopped using their service months ago, but I still use the phone.