# Will my rooted Samsung Galaxy Notes 3 get Android update automatically?

Tags: ota-update, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I have a Samsung Galaxy Notes 3 with Android 4.x. I now know there is Android 5.x.

Will it be upgraded automatically at the right time. If not, should I consider doing it myself?

(Phone is not tied to a carrier, rooted)

Missing in above edit question:

---

I would like to know to what extent phones do get automatic upgrades?
(Like is it only very resent ones)

About looking for manual upgrades - it seems to me that if an upgrade is pushed, it is a reason for it?  So you should probably only do it if you have a good reason, and know what you are doing?

Comment: See  [How do I update Android on my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510) Could you edit out the title? That can invite discussion here. For example, I can post an opinionated  answer that yes, I do upgrade usually and you should consider it too because *blah blah* and then somebody would say, no I don't upgrade usually unless there are too may crashes, and not much app support present, device lags more, *blah blah*. Do you get it now?

Comment: I mean if you have an i-thing, updates are pushed to you.  Of course, with Android there is a greater variation in hardware, so it doesn't happen so fast for all devices.  So I wonder if I should wait until my phone suggest an update?  Or do I need to be more proactive?
Looking at the link, I get the impression updates are just for hackers?

Comment: Olav, what @Firelord is pointing at is: as the question is currently put, it might be subject to closure/deletion (see our [help/dont-ask]). Questions like "Do you (usually) do X" are counted as "Don't ask" here. Better [edit] your post (including its title) to reflect your issue: "Is it recommended to manually update if manufacturers no longer provide automatic updates?" would match that, I bet. Plus in the body asking for the risks of such.

Comment: I think you're talking about OTA (Over-The-Air), which depends on the availability by carrier/device manufacturer. Also, since you're rooted, you probably can't update it using OTA: you need to flash the update manually (or custom ROM which usually is faster than official), or unroot and install the OTA.

Comment: Also, I edited the title to reflect what you seem to concern based on your comment. Of course, you are free to improve it by following Izzy's comment.

Comment: @FireLord English is not my first language, but I think It was clear it was  "Generic You", not "Singular you", esp. after I changed the title to "Would You".  (I used beta versions of Windows 10, but that is not something most users WOULD do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always upgrade my phone because I like to be up to date with sw; indeed I bought a Nexus 5 to get fast upgrades. This way I always have the latest functionalities and improvements. It seems that you will get the lollipop update ([see here](http://samsung.youmobile.org/)), so you may as well install it. If you cannot chose, try reading the change-log to see whether there is a [Stagefright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagefright_%28bug%29) fix or not. If there is update without hesitating!