# How do I discover the latest Android OS available for a device on a carrier?

Tags: updates, ota-update, android-versions, operating-system

How do I discover the latest Android OS version available through standard support channels (no manual rooting or reflashing) for a device? In particular, I am interested in the Samsung Galaxy Note 3 for Verizon. Note, I am not interested in actually installing, just in finding what is available.

Comment: e.g. by checking [How do I update Android on my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/16575) (contains links to "when does my device get the X update). Alternatively: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not rooting or manually flashing, just call Verizon, they'll tell you the latest version they have available.  It's almost certain to be the same that's already there, unless the device has been stored for a good while and thus kept from getting a pushed upgrade.