# Given an Android phone, how can I find out what custom and stock ROMs are compatible?

Tags: custom-roms, rom

I've recently started trying to dabble in custom ROMs, or even just trying to boost an old phone with a newer version of Android, but there doesn't seem to be a conclusive place online to find out what ROMs are supported by what phones (and how to root any given phone), what ROMs are available out there in the world in general, it all seems a bit... messy!

So here's my example for my question: I have an [Obi S453](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/obi-fox-s453-2082), how can I find out what ROMs I might be able to install?

Comment: Search for the phone on XDA. Maybe even in the General section where uncategorized phone ROMs are posted.

Comment: See: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Comment: Given the huge number of brands and their devices, it makes sense that we would never be having a one-stop place for ROMs. Finding a ROM is not hard because wherever a ROM is mentioned, the writer of the post would always mention the device name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site offers a fairly comprehensive coverage to the questions asked by you:

- [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)
- [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)
- [How do I update Android on my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-android-on-my-device)

Coming to your device in particular, it appears there is lack of developer support to create custom ROMs as a quick search (not comprehensive ) did not provide any evidence. Even the OEM, it looks like has not come out with any plans to update to Lollipop, whereas most popular phones have the next version Marshmallow rolled out or in the process of rolling out.

Possible reasons for lack of developer support, in general, could be (i am not a developer, so guessing):

- Chipset being not developer friendly
- Not a popular phone compared to low cost "budget phones"
- Kernel and chip set information not "open source"
- Difficulty in porting custom ROM from another ROM
- OEM not coming up with a improved versions of phone

Answer (score 1):

You find out by checking your model number (my case is SM-G800F). Then you go to the custom ROM and look at the "name" of the build. Mine would be kminilte, which would support even other phones very similar to mine.

You can Google your model number to see. Alternatively, the ROM download page usually contains the market name (so S5 mini and kminilte in small text).

If a device is not supported, you can download a version of a phone very similar to yours. Then either risk and test if it works, or edit the ROM for support on your phone (called porting). There are many guides on porting and rebuilding a ROM similar to your phone.