# Galaxy s5 upgrade from 5.0 to 5.1.1

Tags: updates

How do I manually upgrade my Samsung galaxy S5 from lollipop 5.0 to 5.1.1 as it doesn't want to upgrade by itself. I'm in Namibia and the baseband version is G900HXXU1BOL2.

Comment: Maybe see: [How do I update Android on my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/16575)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I always use a site called [Sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com). They host every firmware made by Samsung. The firmwares are 100% stock and won't trigger Knox. You will need to register an account on their website, but it's free.

You can download the firmware for your device [here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-G900H/). The firmware can be flashed by using a Windows application called Odin (download link in the guide below).

When the firmware is downloaded, flash it on your phone. Here are the steps:

1. Extract the firmware
2. Download [Odin 3.11.1](http://dl.sammobile.com/Odin3-v3.11.1.zip).
3. Extract the Odin zip file.
4. Open Odin.
5. Reboot your phone to download mode by holding the home, power and volume down buttons. Release only the power button when at the Samsung logo, and release all of them when you see a green Android robot. Then press volume up to accept the warning and you'll see DOWNLOADING.
6. Connect the phone to your PC, Odin should now see your device.
7. Add the firmware file to AP/PDA. (The "not responding" is normal, just wait).
8. Make sure re-partition is not checked.
9. Click the start button. The flashing can take some time.

> **Note**: The firmware will not factory reset your phone, so if your phone is stuck booting, don't worry. Just boot to the recovery mode, do a factory reset and reboot the device. This shouldn't be a problem if you're upgrading your device, only when downgrading.