# How to Install marshmallow update on Swipe elite plus ?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, updates, installation

I have swipe elite plus mobile with android lollipop 5.0.2 and I want to install android marshmallow how should I do that?

Comment: You could start by reading our [updates tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/updates/info) and then following up to [How do I update the OS on my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/16575) and other related questions linked there.

Comment: It seems like that device didn't get marshmallow update (yet?). But you can check if there is updates avilable for your device bu built in software updater.

Comment: there is no update from manufacturer.. please suggest me how to install custom rom and which is suitable for my phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be no marshmallow update from manufacturer nor there is custom rom.

So don't hope sale your mobile and get new one

Answer (score 0):

My first reflex would be to check CyanogenMod. Since your device is no longer supported by the manufacturer, you need a custom Android to be able to update.

So your device is [Swipe Elite Plus](http://justswipe.com/swipe-elite-plus/). It is [no longer produced](http://justswipe.com/the-product/smartphones/) by [Swipe](http://justswipe.com/). Swipe owns [FreedomOS](http://justswipe.com/freedom-os/), and it [can be installed on Elite devices](http://justswipe.com/how-to-download-the-freedom-os-on-elite/). It looks like the Swipe devices are [exclusive to India](http://justswipe.com/the-story/).

> We have our eyes on the future, and aim to put India among the top 10 nations in the world. It will be our strategic vision and innovative solutions that will bring leading new tablet technologies to the nation. And soon, to the world.

In order to have something custom developed by someone, that someone must be able to get that device. By being limited to India, it greatly reduces the chances of the device being supported by someone else when the manufacturer will drop it. In short, while it is a good device in itself, it's a bad idea to get one.

Official [CyanogenMod](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/) is not available for the Swipe Elite Plus. Official [TWRP](https://twrp.me/Devices/) is not available for the Swipe Elite Plus. However, there might be unofficial ports.

The best place for finding unofficial stuff is indubitably [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/). However, there are [only one topic](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/device-reviews-and-information/swipe-elite-plus2016-t3398139) about the Elite Swipe Plus. You can look there, but I didn't find anything.

**Your last resort now is to look at these posts :**

[How do I update Android on my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/199649)

[Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/199649)

Comment: where is the link for cynogenMod for swipe elite plus