# Phone Carrier change

Tags: updates

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6 with Nougat.

I have just changed carrier. I'd like to know if I'll receive Nougat updates from the new carrier or I'll have problems.

This because the new carrier has released 10 updates, instead the previous just 2.

Answer (score 1):

No, updates for your phone can only come from the people you got the phone from; i.e. your old carrier. If you got the phone from the phone manufacturer instead of through the carrier, the updates would come from the manufacturer directly, regardless of which carrier you used.

The reason for this is that updates are nothing to do with the phone network or internet gateway. Updates come from whoever built the ROM image on the phone. Normally, this is the manufacturer, but if you buy the phone from the carrier, they usually install their own customized ROM on the phone. They do their own tests on the ROM, and they include changes such as their logos or bloatware apps. Because the carrier builds the ROM, the carrier also has to builds the updates: nobody else can do this. If you change carrier, it changes whose phone network you connect to, but it doesn't change the fact that the old carrier built the ROM image on the phone, so it's still the old carrier who has to build the updates.

This means that if your carrier is slow to provide updates, switching carrier *but keeping the same phone* won't fix that for you. You either need to get a new phone (direct from the manufacturer, if you want better updates and long-term support), or [flash a custom ROM on your phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/12442).